# What is missing in my spatial lag equation model?

Tags: spatial-statistics, regression, geoda

I worked it in GeoDa but I think something is missing.

What is the right equation for a spatial lag model?

In my understanding to predict a variable `Y` is as follows:

```
Y = w_t_homi100 + CONSTANT + p_Unemploy + p_RenterOc
```

But, when I use it, I don´t get predicted values as in column `PREDICTED`. For example, my equation would be:

```
Y = 0.541574 -14.9127 + (783.381*p_Unemploy) + (25.614*p_RenterOc)
```

With this, I don't get `PREDICTED` values `(139.59656, 67.47219, 90.87614)` as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: What software are you trying to implement your equation? Looks like R syntax. If so, have you tried fitting your model using `spatialreg::lagsarlm`?

Comment: I am using GeoDa. Haven´t tried R yet because I firstly want to run spatial lag regression in GeoDa and have the right formula for my regression model.